# Remove-Module removes module unexpectedly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have some modules that look like this (this is a smallest reproducible case of a bigger issue, so bear with me):

`module-a.psm1`:

```
function Write-A {
  Write-Host "A";
}

Export-ModuleMember Write-A;
```

`module-b.psm1`:

```
Import-Module "./module-a";

function Write-B {
  Write-A;
  Write-Host "B";
}

Export-ModuleMember Write-B;
```

These modules are used like this (`fail.ps1`):

```
Import-Module "./module-a";
Import-Module "./module-b";

Write-A;
Write-B;

Remove-Module module-b;

Write-A;
```

I'd expect the following output:

```
A
A
B
A
```

However, I get this output instead:

```
A
A
B
The term 'Write-A' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is corre ct and try again.
At fail.ps1:9 char:8
+ Write-A <<<< ;
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-A:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I can introduce one layer of indirection `module-c.psm1`:

```
Import-Module "./module-a";
Export-ModuleMember Write-A;
```

And then making a working example (`pass.ps1`):

```
Import-Module "./module-c";
Import-Module "./module-b";

Write-A;
Write-B;

Remove-Module module-b;

Write-A;
```

The only thing that I changed in the `ps1` is that I imported `module-c` instead of `module-a`. I get the correct output:

```
A
A
B
A
```

---

What I don't understand is that with `fail.ps1`, removing `module-b` (which uses `module-a` internally), *also* removes `module-a` even though it was imported at the top-level of the session. By introducing the one layer of indirection, it seems that calling `Remove-Module` correctly knows that another module is still referencing it. It's almost as if it's not correctly "counting references" to the modules. I've read about [removing a loaded module](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/05/how-to-remove-a-loaded-module/), but it doesn't seem to explain this behavior. Is this a bug in `Remove-Module` or is this expected behavior?

Comment: I ran and the code and got the expected results... then noticed the `v2.0` tag. I'm leaning towards bug. It may be by design, and something that requires a [ModuleManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-3.0) to get expected behaviour. Also noticed on `v5` that `Get-Module *` and `Get-Command Write-A` correctly listed the relationship in `ExportedCommands` and `Source` respectively. In `v2.0` they were blank.

Comment: @gms0ulman thanks for confirming with PowerShell `v5`. So, it does seem like a bug.